# A conceptual question about elementary optics

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, huygens-principle

My question is about a little piece of information about the basic notion of Huygens Principle.
Consider the following excerpt (Nussenzveig; Curso de Física Básica Vol 4; Brazil;Publisher Blücher)

> The basic ideia of Huygens is that each secondary wave, singly, is too weak to produce perceptible effects. They just produce effects in the envoltory $\sum$, because on it many neighboring secondary waves are reinforced.

I do not understand the meaning of "it many neighboring secondary waves are reinforced".

Comment: Reinforced by means of constructive interference.

Comment: ... or replace "reinforced" with "added together".

Comment: see  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316994209_Making_waves_the_geometric_derivation_of_Huygens'_Principle_for_wave_propagation_and_the_problem_of_the_wake